# Extend an existing interface

Tags: c#, dll, interface

I have encountered a problem. I am using an external library in my program that provides an interface, IStreamable (I don't have the sources of this interface).

I then implement the interface in a DLL that I created, DFKCamera class.

In my current program (which unfortunately I can't fully modify because I am just writing a plugin for it) I then only have access to those methods of DFKCamera that are defined in the interface IStreamable. However, I need to access a different method I have written in DFKCamera for my plugin to work (a method that the rest of the program doesn't use and as such isn't defined in IStreamable).

Is it possible to extend the definition of an interface in C#? If I could extend the IStreamable interface, then I'd have access to the new method.

As is, this is the situation:

```
//In ProgramUtils.DLL, the IStreamable interface is defined
//I have only the .DLL file available
namespace ProgramUtils {
    public interface IStreamable {
       //some methods
    }
}

//In my DFKCamera.DLL
using ProgramUtils;

class DFKCamera: IStreamable {
    //the IStreamable implementation code
    ....
    //the new method I wish to add
    public void newMethod() {}


//In the the program that uses DFKCamera.DLL plugin
//The program stores plugin Camera objects as IStreamable DLLObject;
IStreamable DLLObject = new DFKCamera();
//This means that I cannot access the new method by:
DLLObject.newMethod(); //this doesn't work!
```

Is there a way to extend the IStreamamble interface with the newMethod declaration even though I don't have access to the sources for the IStreamable interface?

I know it's possible to use partial interface definitions to define an interface across files, however that only works if the partial keyword is used across both files and if these are compiled in a single .DLL

I hope this is clear enough!

Comment: Why can't you directly cast to type you want? (Or create and implement new interface on your object which may be better)

Comment: If you're writing a plugin, then it sounds like the `IStreamable` interface is the contract between your plugin and the program. If so, then even if you did expose the new method, how would you instruct the program to call that method? If I'm mistaken, and you are the one actually performing the calls on your object, then of course there's no reason to extend the interface, since you can just cast the object to its actual type and call the method directly.

Comment: @dlev The core program uses IStreamable. I am developing a plugin for the core program that needs to use the same IStreamable object, but I just need to add an extra Getter/Setter methods for a private property (in order for the plugin to work). To be more specific, the core program loads video cameras and plays/stops the live stream. My plugin aims to synchronize two loaded cameras in order to have a stereo vision setup (I need to tell my camera DLL that it is in stereo mode or not, hence the need for a new getter/setter method in the DLL).

Comment: @Voreno Who does the "telling" in this case? The core program? Another part of your DLL? I guess I still think the interesting question is whether or not you can get the core program to execute methods that aren't part of IStreamable. Is there an eventing mechanism it provides, maybe?

Answer (score 19):

You could use an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class IStreamableExtensions
{
    public static void NewMethod(this IStreamable streamable)
    {
        // Do something with streamable.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can inherit from the interface with a custom interface:

```
public interface IDFKStreamable : IStreamable
{
    void NewMethod();
}
```

Then any object which implements the custom interface would also have to implement `IStreamable` and you can just use the custom interface in your code:

```
public class DFKCamera : IDFKStreamable
{
    // IStreamable methods

    public void NewMethod() {}
}

// elsewhere...

IDFKStreamable DLLObject = new DFKCamera();
DLLObject.NewMethod();
```

Since it's still an `IStreamable` you should still be able to use it as one in existing code as well:

```
someOtherObject.SomeMethodWhichNeedsAnIStreamable(DLLObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem is that I cannot modify the "IStreamable DLLObject = new DFKCamera()" line of code, because I am not allowed to modify that line as it's in a core file

Answer (score 2):

At the point that you need to use newMethod(), why not just cast it back to DFKCamera so you can get to it?

```
IStreamable DLLObject = new DFKCamera();
((DFKCamera)DLLObject).newMethod();
```